# How to access error response in the registration api in case there is an error during registration

Tags: angular

I registered a user through a web api.

In the postman if there is an error in any input field then the response is like this

```
{
    "error": {
        "phone": [
            "The phone field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

In the services file

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  registerUser(user: any) { 
    return this.http.post(this.registerUrl, user)
   }
}
```

In the ts file

```
constructor(private reg: AuthService) { }
    registered: boolean = false;
     const user = {
          first_name: e.controls.first_name.value,
          last_name: e.controls.last_name.value,
          phone: e.controls.phone.value,

        };

    this.registered = this.reg.registerUser(user) ? true : false;
```

To use them for form validation and confirmation checks, how to get the error fields and also the success token if the user is registered because postman shows success token if the user is registered successfully. This is a post request and not a get request, so is it possible to get those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the httpClient post request is returning an Observable.

**this registerUser method is returning Observable because all httpClient methods does:**

```
registerUser(user: any): Observable<any> { 
    return this.http.post(this.registerUrl, user)
}
```

so you should subscribe to that observable to get the response returning from the api, so your code should be like this:

**In the component ts file**

```
const user = {
      first_name: e.controls.first_name.value,
      last_name: e.controls.last_name.value,
      phone: e.controls.phone.value,

    };

this.reg.registerUser(user).subscribe(
   (res) => {
       this.registered = res === true ? true : false;
       // you should be more specific in how api response look like
   },
   (err) => {
       console.log(err); // or do whatever you want with the error
   }
);
```